# Correcting alignment while printing in java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, alignment

I have made a switch-case Restaurant program which has the following snippet:

```
for(int r=0;r<=17;r++)
{
    while(qty[r]>0)
    {
        System.out.println(qty[r]+" X "+O[r]+"              "+l[r]);
        break;
    }
}
//qty has the quantity(int) ; O has the Item name (String) and l has the cost (int)
```

Due to the difference in the length of the string, the output is not uniform- it isn't properly aligned.

The output:

```
*********************************************************
*********************************************************
**************************BILL***************************

Thu Feb 09 22:01:36 IST 2017

Your phone number - 9821809843
Bill number is 4180536
You have ordered :
Item Name with quantity            Price
1 X Fried Raviolli              400
1 X Potato Fries with Jalapeno and Cheese Dip              800

The total bill amount is Rs.1200

Hope you enjoyed. Visit us again soon!
```

Any ideas as to how I can correct this?

Comment: @nhouser9 Yes, that does somewhat solve my problem. But since I am a newbie, I am not sure how I will edit my snippet. Please do me a favor and  show me how it can be done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer below. Please remember to upvote and accept if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your print statement with something like this:

```
System.out.printf("%d X %-50s %d", qty[r], O[r], l[r]);
```

Here is some documentation on this method: http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

On a side note, please name your variables descriptively. If you get in the habit of naming an array `l` and `O` you will find writing any harder projects almost impossible. The comment

```
//qty has the quantity(int) O has the Item name (String) and l has the cost (int)
```

Should not be necessary, the arrays should just be named something like `qty`, `name`, and `cost`. Even better practice would be to make an object that stores all three of these fields instead.

Comment: What is % used here for?

Comment: is this code compilable?

Comment: @LinuxGeek adding some documentation to my answer to address your comment

Comment: It isn't ! I get the first error at + before O[r] and then at the time of execution

Comment: @LinuxGeek it should be fixed, i just had a + sign in the wrong place. tested on my machine and it works fine. see the edited answer.

Comment: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: null(in java.util.Formatter

Comment: @LinuxGeek you can add \n to the string to print a new line. it's pulling the quantity from your array, so there must be a bug in your array in that case.